# Convert user entered value to dollar currency

Tags: c#, currency

I have a scenario where a user enters a value in as a string and I need to convert it to 
a dollar currency and show it on the form. I have tried with the below approach.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string money = txtbox.Text;
    string currency = Convert.ToDecimal(txtbox.Text, new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("C");
    money = currency;
    Response.Write(money);
}
```

The issue is when user enters 56789 the result is shown as $56,789.00 where I do not want the unnecessary zeros after "." Where as when the user enters as 56789.67 the result is shown as $56,789.67 which is expected. Please help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Decimal currency = Convert.ToDecimal(txtbox.Text, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    string money = currency.ToString("C");

    if (currency % 1 == 0) {
        money = money.Substring(0, money.Length - 3);
    }

    Response.write(money);
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/86bZmu).

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck! :)

Comment: You didn't declare a type for `money`; or am I missing something?

Comment: the compiler throwing error @ 1st line "Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".And when changed the datatype of curreny to decimal the above solution is not working

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wrote it rather quickly - there were a few bugs, but it should be good now, I think. I'm double checking

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel thanks for ur solution...may i know the above solution doesnt work when user enters 5789.7345 the result is shown as $5,789.73  instead of $5,789.7345.correct me if im wrong

Comment: I just updated my demo, again, to include the "$5,789.7345" example that you gave

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Thanks for ur solution and i guess even ur prev approach works rt?

Comment: The conversion to currency actually takes care of the extra decimal places. My original solution will work. Use that, not the one with `.LastIndexOf`, as it will be more expensive (though only slightly so).